# How to make a path in objective C?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm working with Objective C (IOS) and I found this code:

```
Person *aPerson = <#Get a Person#>;
NSString *archivePath = <Path for the archive#>;
BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:aPerson toFile:archivePath];
```

I would like to know what the archivePath should be to save the file in documents directory.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out archivePath:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory 
NSString *archivePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Person"];
```